# find a general formula between two parameters using curve-fit

Tags: python, matlab, curve-fitting, curves

I am trying to study the relationship between two parameters say `A` and `B` for an image.

For a single scene S1, I take 20 images back-to-back where all 20 images will have different values of parameter `A`. Now for each of 20 images I calculate parameter `B`. Thus, I have 20 pairs of type `(A, B)`.

Now I plot all 20 `(A, B)` points.

I repeat the same experiment for different scenes and get curves which look similar. This is how all the curves look like: [Example curve](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ64VR72kXU4sX2bPaYZ38eJtDwwj63EocRRKlplZuwzYCP5Ltx)

I want to establish a formula linking parameters `A` and `B`. I decided to use curve-fitting (using Python) and tried to fit a polynomial curve `ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d`. This curve fits very well most of the time, but for each graph I get different values of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. The values vary too much.

Next, I tried fitting a logarithmic curve `a + b * log(x)`. This time, the curve does not always fit very well to the points and I get values of `a` varying from 7 to 9 and values of `b` varying from 1 to 3.

Basically my question is how should I go about establishing a formula between `A` and `B` so that for a given image if I have value of parameter `A`, I can get a fair estimate of parameter `B`?

Following are sample data points for parameter `A` and `B` respectively:

```
A = [0.9937759763768161, 0.9929152405279837, 0.9931066175878016, 0.9931907432668384, 0.9423758456906559, 0.9423108644829163, 0.8950448401371942, 0.891681991390553, 0.8465614087427353, 0.805345556595838, 0.7662998080069015, 0.7314247255399298, 0.6984452544936371, 0.6367965670718196, 0.5836881571632964, 0.4988198092947567, 0.4194923476465984, 0.33213924154453156, 0.22415360562956688, 0.11320564921875846]

B = [7.1924877201252109, 7.2179850206954717, 7.2104191677025398, 7.2052736759243174, 7.3607976206941599, 7.3592349109473805, 7.4487191455800605, 7.4675352495474385, 7.5513534938320701, 7.5711664827868503, 7.5349750797299357, 7.4872747506190747, 7.3718597264801442, 7.2183573562424082, 7.0814398229980107, 6.7632755526248989, 6.4009932656267612, 5.8645747001035851, 4.9334148033003622, 3.3773511239822742]
```

The data points are in order with each other.

Comment: As cross-posting on SE sites is discouraged, it's good practice to delete your question on SO.

Comment: In statistical terms, your two "parameters" are best thought of as variables. As you have just 20 pairs for an image, why not post sample data here? It's rare that a cubic has any scientific value, unless there are independent grounds for thinking that it should hold (some would say the last clause is empty). For monotonic relationships, it is not especially helpful.

Comment: When you say fitting "exactly", I presume you just mean "very well".

Comment: You get very different coefficients for each image (no surprise) but seem to want a general formula for all images. How do you reconcile those goals? That is: you haven't given a reason why the same functional form should be expected to perform well for all images. One statistical approach is that you pool all the $a, b$ pairs and then estimate, or at least check to see what that looks like. Another, better but more challenging, is that you use properties of the images to help model image-to-image variation in $a, b$,

Comment: @NickCox, Thanks for your input. I've deleted the question from SO. I'll post the sample data.  And yes it should be fitting "very well" and not "exactly" :).

Comment: @NickCox, This is in response to your last comment. For a given image, it is known that if you increase value of parameter A, B also increases and vice-versa. To see what the curve looks like check the 'Example curve' link I have attached in the question. That's why I am assuming that I can come out with a formula which takes one parameter and fairly estimates the other.

Comment: @NickCox, I'm wondering if I pool all the a,b pairs, what it will look like. I will attach the graph if possible. Further, using properties of the image to model image-to-image variation in a,b is surely challenging.

Comment: OK, if the relationship is known to monotonic, a cubic is definitely to be avoided. The coefficients will just be fighting with each other to capture minor details. I can't add positive suggestions on this information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24419/discussion-between-stalin-and-nick-cox).

Comment: My personal view is that it's better to keep things open and let others contribute.

Comment: @NickCox, Ok. I'll update the sample data points in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is more by way of extra comments than a full answer, but I have a graph and summary statistics that can only be well shown in an answer.

There are more decimal places here than may make sense, but they show up details that could be crucial:

```
    Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
           A |        20    .7150387    .2726499   .1132056    .993776
           B |        20    6.880924    1.051601   3.377351   7.571167
```

1. The summaries for `A` are suggestive of a measure bounded by 0 and 1, but what are the limits? Are 0 and 1 defined in principle? Attainable in practice? What about values beyond 0 and 1?
2. The range of possibilities for `B` is not clear. But again any comment you can make about bounds in principle and bounds in practice could be very helpful.
3. **The sample data make clear to me that there is a subtle but definite turning point in this case around `A` $\sim 0.8$, so contrary to comments earlier made. relationships cannot be said to be all monotonic.**

[image]

Note that a curve of the form $a + b \log A$ will not capture the turning-point, as it can only be monotonic. (Presumably your $x \equiv A$.) Quadratics and higher polynomials can naturally possess turning points.

4. To me the points suggest a well-defined relationship: the problem is merely that it seems hard to suggest a functional form for that on the information to date! As in points 1 and 2, whatever information you can provide on what the data are, and how they should behave, should help greatly. Subject-matter comments can sometimes rule some analyses out as physically (biologically, ...) absurd or unhelpful and sometimes rule analyses in as being the opposite.  My most specific concern is that an upper limit of 1 should feature even in simple modelling if it is a real limit.

Comment: I will answer your points one by one. Yes the values of A are bounded by 0 and 1.

Comment: Hi Nick, to better answer the points you have raised, you can refer to detailed information in this question here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24264/relation-between-luminance-and-eigen-values-of-an-image/24333#24333, you will get to know what exactly the parameters are and other things. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the cross-reference. You add much substantive detail but I don't think I can push my answer forward. Your stance on failure of monotonicity seems to be just that you don't understand it. However, it appears to be real in the one dataset given here.

Comment: Yes. The relationship is not at all monotonic. The turning point almost always appeared after ~0.80 key-value. The keyvalues above 0.80 are not much useful to me, so I discarded them in favor of monotonicity.

Comment: Sorry, but I am no longer much focused on this old thread. To get others' attention, you would need to add content to the question; otherwise  this is just an old thread, abandoned for 20 days,  that most active members would not scan.